# separate mat-horizontal-stepper labels and content

Tags: angular, angular-material2, angular5, angular-material-stepper

I want the stepper labels to be shown in a toolbar, but the content to be shown in another div.

something like:

```html
<div>
 <mat-horizontal-stepper md-stretch-steppers="always">
  <mat-step>
   <ng-template matStepLabel>Head 1</ng-template>
  </mat-step>
  <mat-step>
   <ng-template matStepLabel>Head 1</ng-template>
  </mat-step>
 </mat-horizontal-stepper>
</div>

<div>
 <any-components></any-components>
</div>

<div id="contents">
  [contents goes here]
</div>
```

can i separate the stepper labels from the content?

Comment: I am not quite sure what you are trying to accomplish. 1. Do you want the labels of the stepper to be viewed inside a toolbar (just for the optics)? 2. or do you want to use components as content. 3. why are you trying to seperate the content from the stepper?