# Stepper content in different div

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, material-design

the only question remotely close to mine I have found is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48614694/separate-mat-horizontal-stepper-labels-and-content).
I want to make a custom stepper with the tabs / navigation in a different div then the content for design purposes.

I would have a stepper like this

```
<app-main-title title="VPN"></app-main-title>
<div class="stepper-container">
  <div class="stepper-wrapper">
    <mat-horizontal-stepper class="mat-horizontal-content-container">
      <mat-step
              label="{{ 'Creating' }}">
      </mat-step>
      <mat-step
              label="{{ 'Installing' }}">
      </mat-step>
      <mat-step
              label="{{ 'Connecting' }}">
      </mat-step>
    </mat-horizontal-stepper>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="main-content-container">
  <p>CONTENT SHOULD BE DISPLAYED HERE/p>
</div>
```

How would I go about this? The closest thing I've found to what I want is using a router store and list-items, but I'd like to use the functionality built-in the [material stepper](https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/overview).